# Datagrid not populating past headers

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, datagrid

Thanks in advance for any help.  I've been working with the tutorial listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707362%28v=vs.91%29.aspx), but have run into an issue.  I'm attempting to populate a datagrid in silverlight, but when I submit the button click, it will return the headers for columns but no data.  I know data is in the system, so I'm confused why it's going to get the headers but not the actual data to populate.  Code from my MainPage.xaml.cs and my data domain are below.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace SandCherryDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private SandCherryViewContext _sandCherryContext = new SandCherryViewContext();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StatusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StatusButton.IsEnabled = false;
            LoadOperation<SandCherryView> loadOp = this._sandCherryContext.Load(this._sandCherryContext.GetEQPByStatusQuery(StatusValue.Text), DataLoadedCallback, null);
            SandCherryGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
        }

        void DataLoadedCallback(LoadOperation<SandCherryView> loadOperation)
        {
            StatusButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

SandCherryViewService.cs

```
 [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class SandCherryViewService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<Charter_SandCherryEntities>
    {
        [Query(IsComposable=false)]
        public IQueryable<SandCherryView> GetEQPByStatus(string status)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews.Where(e => e.StatusDescr.StartsWith(status) == true);
        }

        // TODO:
        // Consider constraining the results of your query method.  If you need additional input you can
        // add parameters to this method or create additional query methods with different names.
        // To support paging you will need to add ordering to the 'SandCherryViews' query.
        public IQueryable<SandCherryView> GetSandCherryViews()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews;
        }

        public void InsertSandCherryView(SandCherryView sandCherryView)
        {
            if ((sandCherryView.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(sandCherryView, EntityState.Added);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews.AddObject(sandCherryView);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateSandCherryView(SandCherryView currentSandCherryView)
        {
            this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews.AttachAsModified(currentSandCherryView, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentSandCherryView));
        }

        public void DeleteSandCherryView(SandCherryView sandCherryView)
        {
            if ((sandCherryView.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(sandCherryView, EntityState.Deleted);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews.Attach(sandCherryView);
                this.ObjectContext.SandCherryViews.DeleteObject(sandCherryView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is not loaded yet. Try setting the `ItemsSource` of your grid in `DataLoadedCallBack` event -

```
void DataLoadedCallback(LoadOperation<SandCherryView> loadOperation)
{
   StatusButton.IsEnabled = true;
   SandCherryGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
}
```

Comment: No luck.  After I copied it over it it wouldn't even load headers (though i guess this could point to a bigger problem?)

Comment: Have you checked that `loadOp.Entities` retuns some data?

Comment: Just checked and it's not (probably something I should have checked first!)  So I'm guessing this is an issue with the query I'm running rather than on the "silverlight" side so to speak.  Thoughts?  Thanks much by the way.

Comment: Yeah, on UI side all seems to be in place. Check the service you are using, must be something in there..

Comment: I'll dig around.  Thanks for the suggestions!